# Go lang installation issues with ./make.bash ubuntu->windows

Tags: bash, go, sudo, bootstrapper

I have tried to search and found a lot of topics which are related to my problem, but none of them I could follow to success. 
I can `go run` and `go get` with no issues, but I need to compile into windows and there I have problems please see bellow

```
mikhail@mikhail-desktop:/usr/lib/go/src$ sudo ./make.bash 
# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
go tool dist: $GOROOT is not set correctly or not exported
    GOROOT=/usr/share/go
    /usr/share/go/include/u.h does not exist
mikhail@mikhail-desktop:/usr/lib/go/src$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/mikhail/Documents/FL/0go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
mikhail@mikhail-desktop:/usr/lib/go/src$
```

By some reasons it thinks the GOROOT is `/usr/share/go` while it actually `/usr/lib/go`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` can clean environment variables, to check if that is the case here, run `sudo $(which go) env` and check if the output is what you expect. If not, you can keep the enviroment of your user by using the `-E` flag: `sudo -E ./make.bash`.

Comment: Thank you! I had same thoughts, that may be I need to set up EXPORTS in /root/.bashrc ... But then I decided to try to get it install from source, and it worked... I can not verify now your suggestion, but I nearly sure you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it somehow connected to Debian/Ubuntu thing. I seen such issues but related to 0.9. version.

I have installed go from source into ~/go and then everything went quite OK, now I can compile to windows from ubuntu with help [Introduction to cross compilation with go](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go) and [LiteIDE](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide).